# Installing dvipng to MiKTeX on Win XP machine?

Tags: windows-xp, miktex, tex, dvipng

I'm completely new to TeX. I have installed MiKTeX on a Win XP machine (installation went fine), and now I would like to install dvipng. I need it to be able to use TeX in a flashcard program I use called Mnemosyne.

How is dvipng installed? I have downloaded 'dvipng-1.12.tar.gz', and when I extract it I get a folder and a bunch of files which I have no idea what to do with.

Could anyone help me?

Many thanks,

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to install dvipng separately from MiKTeX

Comment: You're right - there is a dvipng in MikTeX, but it's far from the latest & greatest.  I'm assuming (you what happens when...) jdelage was trying to get an updated release of dvipng & then didn't understand why there was no exe, but instead a bunch of .c & .h files.

Comment: When I installed MiKTeX, I didn't know that it included dvipng.  Your 2 answers together resolve my problem, as I should be OK with any (reasonably good) version of dvipng for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The files in dvipng are the source code and build files you need to build dvipng on your computer.  It uses configure, so on Windows XP, you'll need [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or a similar gnu/linux/*nix system to do anything with this.  You'll also need a c compiler, which you can get as part of cygwin.  That's going to be a lot of software for 1 converter.

I would recommend another tool.  I use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) a lot, but I think you'd have to use dvips (should be incl. in MikTeX) to create a postscript file first, then imagemagick could convert it to png.