# dvipng with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, dvipng

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing dvipng to MiKTeX on Win XP machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/50633/installing-dvipng-to-miktex-on-win-xp-machine)

How do I install dvipng on a Windows 7 system?

Comment: Are you trying to install from the source code or have you located a Windows binary you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way is to download and install MikTeX - http://miktex.org/2.9/setup.

See [Installing dvipng to MiKTeX on Win XP machine?](https://superuser.com/q/50633/45478)